# /usr/sbin/and using up the entire CPU coure

Tags: 18.04, server, intel, cpu, php7

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS
Kernel 5.5.2-050502-generic

and since a while now I've seen this /usr/sbin/and popping up in htop, always using entire full core of the server, not really sure why, but it is very suspicious and cripples the performance of my server.

Oddly enough it's not running straight after reboot, but seems to start at about 7 days after server bootup.

Below are contents of the /usr/sbin/and copied to a file in a download link
https://www.files.olokos.pl/wl/?id=7MJibQCadrdRSsPU5l10jdFWNR5NtVx2

Comment: This seems to be very useful, but why it's hogging the entire core? I doubt this is normal operation of the Auto Nice Daemon :(

Comment: I doubt that you really want to know "why". It's more constructive if you ask "is this a bug?" I think so, and I think you should file a bug report.

Comment: I do really want to get to the bottom of this, this is exactly why I came here. Where would I file the report though? I would do that in the meanwhile.

Comment: Well, you can report it an Launchpad...but that just means a volunteer would upstream it to the [Debian Tracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?src=and). Were I in your shoes, I would skip those intermediaries and go straight to the [developer's bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/and/bugs/stats/).